# Removing previous List<> item in an enumerator C#

Tags: c#, list, erase, enumerator

```
///main
while(true)
{
    List<string>.Enumerator instEnum = messagesList.GetEnumerator();
    InstantaiteObject(instEnum);
}

///enumerator
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
.....
}
```

I need to delete an item I just worked with every step of the loop inside that enumeratror.
If it's impossible to do within the enumerator, I need to remove all items I worked with from said List inside main.
 Is there a built-in elegant way of doing it?

Comment: What are your conditions for removing the element?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the source of an `IEnumerable` while you are iterating over it through the interface invalidates the `Enumerator`. Therefore it is not directly possible. 
That being said there are several workarounds since you are working with a `List<>`

1. You can iterate over a copy of the list  and remove the items that need to be removed from the original one(usually inefficient). This will not invalidate your Enumerator
2. Use the indexers instead.

Example for 1:

```
foreach(var myItem in messageList.ToList())
{
    //Do stuff...

    if(whateverContition == true)
    {
        messageList.Remove(myItem);
    }
}
```

Example for 2:

```
for(int i = 0; i < messageList.Count; i++)
{
    string myItem = messageList[i];

    //Do stuff...

    if(whateverContition == true)
    {
        messageList.RemoveAt(i);
        --i;
    }
}
```

If you only have access to `IEnumerable` you can do either #1 or e.g. Ryan's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added necessary details. There are many possible methods you could use. For example, if you could copy the list, process the first element, and then remove the first element:

```
var instEnum = new List<string>(messagesList);
while (instEnum.Count > 0)
{
    // Process item
    // ...
    // then remove it
    instEnum.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

There are many variations of this (using an index so you may skip items, remove items, etc), so without knowing more about your situation we can't offer more help.